# How to list all attributes of sklearn.datasets object?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, attributes

Coming from R, where I can inspect the internal structure of any object with `str()`, I'm puzzled by how to do the same in Python. The standard is to use `dir(my_object)`, but it does not list all attributes, including very important ones. For example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
dir(iris)
```

`dir(iris)` does not list the most important attributes, such as `iris.data`, `iris.target`, etc.

Am I supposed to read the docs to know about these attributes, or is there a way to find out just from looking inside the object?

Comment: A [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637281/what-are-python-pandas-equivalents-for-r-functions-like-str-summary-and-he) one.

Comment: dir(iris) does now.

Answer (score 7):

The datasets are loaded into a dict-like object, so you can find the data that are stored in the dict rather than everything in the namespace which includes the standard dict methods.

```
In [2]: iris = datasets.load_iris()

In [3]: iris.keys()
Out[3]: ['target_names', 'data', 'target', 'DESCR', 'feature_names']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the attributes:

```
In [10]: iris.data
Out[10]: array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
                [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
                [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
                ...

In [11]: iris.target
Out[11]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [13]: iris.target_names
Out[13]: array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], 
         dtype='|S10')

In [14]: iris.feature_names
Out[14]: ['sepal length (cm)',
          'sepal width (cm)',
          'petal length (cm)',
          'petal width (cm)']
```

The last one will give you a detailed description of the dataset with some summary stats.

```
In [15]: iris.DESCR
Out[15]: 'Iris Plants Database\n\nNotes\n-----\nData Set Characteristics:\n    :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three
```

I truncated the output of `iris.data`and `iris.DESCR`. [Here are the dataset docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris)