# Why is my pandas df all object data types as opposed to e.g. int, string etc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Over on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637281/what-are-python-pandas-equivalents-for-r-functions-like-str-summary-and-he) SO post someone suggests using df.info() to get information about a a pandas df, including the data types of each field.

Pasting part of this persons answer here:

```
train.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 12 columns):
PassengerId    891 non-null int64
Survived       891 non-null int64
Pclass         891 non-null int64
Name           891 non-null object
Sex            891 non-null object
Age            714 non-null float64
SibSp          891 non-null int64
Parch          891 non-null int64
Ticket         891 non-null object
Fare           891 non-null float64
Cabin          204 non-null object
Embarked       889 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(5), object(5)
memory usage: 83.6+ KB
```

I tried this on my own pandas data frame:

```
sessions1DF.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 69085 entries, 0 to 69084
Data columns (total 10 columns):
ga:date                69085 non-null object
ga:hour                69085 non-null object
ga:dimension1          69085 non-null object
ga:dimension2          69085 non-null object
ga:userType            69085 non-null object
ga:landingpagePath     69085 non-null object
ga:deviceCategory      69085 non-null object
ga:sessions            69085 non-null object
ga:goal1Completions    69085 non-null object
ga:bounces             69085 non-null object
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 5.3+ MB
```

Everything is an object where I expected some combination of strings and numbers. Here is the head:

```
sessions1DF.head()
Out[13]: 
    ga:date ga:hour    ...     ga:goal1Completions ga:bounces
0  20180605      18    ...                       0          0
1  20180605      18    ...                       0          1
2  20180605      18    ...                       0          0
3  20180605      18    ...                       0          1
4  20180605      18    ...                       0          0

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

(I wish I knew how to force pandas `head()` to show me all the features, not just the 4 it showed me above).

sessions1DF actually has a field called "dimension1" which is supposed to be a string and I would like to join it with another data frame sessions2DF, where they both share the same field "dimension1". So I'd like to join them on dimension1.

Is there something "wrong" with my pandas data frame? Is there a way to "extract" all the object to be the actual data within them? Presumably my data frame is not in a normal format, where each field is simply a vector of data.

Is there a way to alter my data frame so that if I type `sessions1DF.info()` I will get a result similar to the one pasted at the top, with each column being a string, int etc as opposed to an object?

Comment: Hi , I faced the similar challenges today. Following were my findings: a) I had multiple headers b) missing values c) "." & "-" . Since i pulled the data from database, i had multiple headers due to incorrect adjustment of linesize and pagesize. I manually deleted the records and it worked perfectly and had int, float, obj all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['a','d','f'],
                   'dicts':[{'a':4}, {'c':8}, {'e':9}],
                   'lists':[[4,8],[7,8],[3]],
                   'tuples':[(4,8),(7,8),(3,)],
                   'sets':[set([1,8]), set([7,3]), set([0,1])] })

print (df)
      dicts   lists    sets strings  tuples
0  {'a': 4}  [4, 8]  {8, 1}       a  (4, 8)
1  {'c': 8}  [7, 8]  {3, 7}       d  (7, 8)
2  {'e': 9}     [3]  {0, 1}       f    (3,)
```

All values have same [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
dicts      object
lists      object
sets       object
strings    object
tuples     object
dtype: object
```

But `type` is different, if need check it by loop:

```
for col in df:
    print (df[col].apply(type))

0    <class 'dict'>
1    <class 'dict'>
2    <class 'dict'>
Name: dicts, dtype: object
0    <class 'list'>
1    <class 'list'>
2    <class 'list'>
Name: lists, dtype: object
0    <class 'set'>
1    <class 'set'>
2    <class 'set'>
Name: sets, dtype: object
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: strings, dtype: object
0    <class 'tuple'>
1    <class 'tuple'>
2    <class 'tuple'>
Name: tuples, dtype: object
```

Or first value of columns:

```
print (type(df['strings'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df['dicts'].iat[0]))
<class 'dict'>

print (type(df['lists'].iat[0]))
<class 'list'>

print (type(df['tuples'].iat[0]))
<class 'tuple'>

print (type(df['sets'].iat[0]))
<class 'set'>
```

Or by [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
print (df.applymap(type))
         strings           dicts           lists           tuples  \
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'dict'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'tuple'>   
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'dict'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'tuple'>   
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'dict'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'tuple'>   

            sets  
0  <class 'set'>  
1  <class 'set'>  
2  <class 'set'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing may be related to how you have read in the data to the dataframe. Assuming you used one of the pandas readers,  such as the csv reader:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv')
```

you may have a file that has one or more of these conditions in it:

1. A string character representing missing values
2. Multiple headers or footers where the type in that column is non numeric.
3. Weird rows in the middle of the table that break type inference.

The pandas reader (or any read trying to parse delimited data and figure out data types on the fly) has to look at the data down a column and ask itself "is everything in this column a number?" If so,  then cast the type into a number (int or float).   If the parser / reader see a string that is not a number in a column,  that whole column will be cast to "object" instead of int or float.

To explore that possibility,  you can open your text file with a text editor (notepad++,  visual studio code,  etc.) and visually check the structure.

If the file is too big to open and scan visually (69,000 rows is not that big),  you can try various options with the pandas reader function.  To see those,  try typing this:

```
pd.read_csv?
```

To view all the options that are available.  For example,  you may want to just try reading the first n rows,   or try skipping a few rows at the top,  or specifying the character that represents missing values,  so it knows to skip over that when checking types.

You can even pass in the per column data types to the read so it "knows" which columns are numeric,  which are strings,  which are date_time,  etc.

Also,  in pandas you can control the options so that when you view a dataframe,  you see all columns,  and not the … indication,   See the pandas.options.display on the pandas website.

[pandas options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This exactly solved my issue.