# How to return multiple objects from R script executed in Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

So I am struggling to use the `rpy2` package to integrate some workflow between R and Python.

For example, imagine I'm trying to run a Python script that does a linear regression in R and I want to return all of the elements of that (in reality I'm trying to do something much more complicated than this).

I execute the following in Python (calling R; This assumes you have `rpy2` installed):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
test = ro.r('''
            # Load in data
            df <- mtcars
            # Run regression
            out = lm(formula='mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt',data=df)
            ''')
```

And now what? I have a questions:

1. How do I pull the various elements from the result? In R they would be `out$coefficients` and `out$residuals`, etc. I know there is documentation for this, but I'm a bit lost. Ideally, I would want the elements in useful formats, so pandas dataframes or indexed lists, etc.
2. What happens to `df`? `robjects.r()` seems to just save whatever the last thing you gave and throw away everything else. I suppose I can work with this, but it's not ideal.
3. Related to 2: Is there a much much better way to do this? In general if someone could put forward a "best practice" for this sort of thing, that would be helpful, since I'm sure that there are many people interested in using Python, but occasionally have a very custom function they need to call using R but they don't want to get to fancy with the integration. Perhaps a way to call an R function using Pythonic input arguments would be great.

Comment: Any sensible interface would give you some sort of list-like structure indexed by the same names as you would find in R. Doesn't python have an analogous  function to R's `str`. It must. Search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637281/what-are-python-pandas-equivalents-for-r-functions-like-str-summary-and-he

Comment: Sure. I was able to (with the above situation) pull the coefficients for instance with: `rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.ri2py(test.rx2('coefficients'))`, but that still doesn't answer what has happened to `df` in `test` and it also belies how clunky this solution is for what should be a basic functionality of `rpy2`

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be accessing R functionality via an interface which would be expected to return only the value of `out`, at least if I understand typical functional programming. Were you expecting all of the R environment to be returned to python? I suppose that's possible, but it's not what I would expect as an experienced R user. Can you point to documentation that suggests all objects in the R environment should be available after the return of control to python?

Comment: I suppose I just think it is odd that that script does not return the entire environment because I didn't make a particular function call. Theoretically `df` is just as valid as `out` to be accessed through `test`. The only difference is the order in which they were called. I'm writing on here because the documentation here is not very good...

Comment: Even following a multi-line expression outside a function, R only returns the result of the last evaluation. The way to return multiple objects would be to wrap `list(.)` around them, just as that is the way when using functions.

Comment: So that’s really what’s going on, the function is grabbing whatever is last in working memory, not the whole environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q.1: How do I pull the various elements from the result?

Ans.1: After you run your R script:

```
test = ro.r(your_R_script)
```

You can use this code to print out all the `names` and `values` in the `test` object.

```
# iterate on names and values
# be careful output is v long
for n,v in test.items():
    print(n)
    print(v)
```

To list all available `names`, run this code:

```
test.names
```

The output:

```
StrVector with 12 elements.
'coeffici... 'residuals' 'effects' 'rank' ... 'xlevels' 'call'  'terms' 'model'
```

To print values of the 'residuals', run this:

```
test[test.names.index('residuals')]
```

Q.2: What happens to df?

Ans.2: It is still available in R environment until you delete it. You can run simple R code to check:

```
ro.r('''
        # View dataframe
        df
        ''')
```

Q.3: Is there a much much better way to do this?

Ans.3: (No answer.)