# Difference between describe() and summary() in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

What is the difference between `summary()` and `describe()` ?

It seems that they both serve the same purpose. I didn't manage to find any differences (if any).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we are passing any args then these functions works for different purposes:

**`.describe()`** function takes `cols:String*`(columns in df) as optional args.

**`.summary()`** function takes `statistics:String*`(count,mean,stddev..etc) as optional args.

**Example:**

```
scala> val df_des=Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")).toDF("id","name")
scala> df_des.describe().show(false) //without args
//Result:
//+-------+---+----+
//|summary|id |name|
//+-------+---+----+
//|count  |3  |3   |
//|mean   |2.0|null|
//|stddev |1.0|null|
//|min    |1  |a   |
//|max    |3  |c   |
//+-------+---+----+
scala> df_des.summary().show(false) //without args
//+-------+---+----+
//|summary|id |name|
//+-------+---+----+
//|count  |3  |3   |
//|mean   |2.0|null|
//|stddev |1.0|null|
//|min    |1  |a   |
//|25%    |1  |null|
//|50%    |2  |null|
//|75%    |3  |null|
//|max    |3  |c   |
//+-------+---+----+
scala> df_des.describe("id").show(false) //descibe on id column only
//+-------+---+
//|summary|id |
//+-------+---+
//|count  |3  |
//|mean   |2.0|
//|stddev |1.0|
//|min    |1  |
//|max    |3  |
//+-------+---+
scala> df_des.summary("count").show(false) //get count summary only
//+-------+---+----+
//|summary|id |name|
//+-------+---+----+
//|count  |3  |3   |
//+-------+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The first operation to perform after importing data is to get some sense of what it looks like. For numerical columns, knowing the descriptive summary statistics can help a lot in understanding the distribution of your data. The function describe returns a DataFrame containing information such as number of non-null entries (count), mean, standard deviation, and minimum and maximum value for each numerical column.
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html
Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you have answered how `summary()` and `describe()` are different

Comment: Both are same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637281/what-are-python-pandas-equivalents-for-r-functions-like-str-summary-and-he/42222647

Answer (score -1):

Both have same functionality but the api syntax is just different. Hope this helps